# class not found exception after replacing library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jena, classnotfoundexception

**UPDATE** (I have updated the question since I only experience the following error)

I have replaced a Jena library (to get the newer version) in my Eclipse web application. Though I can use the new library and compile without error, I receive the the following exceptions when my code reaches the methods of Jena.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.packages.servlets.CreatePatternServlet] in context with path [/TempProject] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom
```

I have log4j.properties in my project and other solutions I have came across did not seem to help.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The Jena library depends on `slf4j`, so you need to get the `slf4j-api.jar` on your classpath. If you use Maven, you can simple add the [Jena library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hp.hpl.jena/jena/2.6.4) with this XML snippet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hp.hpl.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and it would pull all the dependencies without any additional work on your part.

Comment: actually i was using jena before, the problem came up with the current version. one quick question: is there a difference between adding jar to classpath and buildpath ?

Comment: do you also have a suggestion for the first error  ?

Comment: If it is on the build path, but not on the classpath, it will cause a noclassdeffoundexception, if it is not provided by e.g. an application server.

Comment: i got it but one thing : to which file do i add this ? if it is pom.xml, it doesn't exist in my project

Comment: Yes, it would go to the `pom.xml`, that is why I said *"if you use Maven"*. If you don't, then you need to do the dependency management manually.

Comment: i am using luna,
found pom.xml of jena libs but they seemed to have this piece of code, yet i cannot edit them

Comment: Use artifact org.apache.jena:apache-jena-lib:pom:2.12.1

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when I added the libraries also into lib folder under WEB-INF.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: why not? i mentioned that i was using jena and specified a class that was not found. And provided that problem was solved when I copied the jar files into lib folder under WEB-INF. How come it is not an answer ?